# how do I prevent left side of page from being cut off when resizing IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am working on our new corporate website.  I took over for someone else.  I just resized the IE8 window to make it smaller and the left side of my page is cut off.  I get a scroll bar at the bottom of the window, but it won't let me see part of the left side of the page.  There's nothing weird about the site.  It's html with some javascript and a couple of stylesheets that were created by the previous developer.

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?  Or force the bottom scroll bar to allow me to go all the way to the left side of the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for some rules in CSS styles with margins set to negative values. Probably the positions  of your containers got messy after you change the size of the window.

Comment: That was it.  Unfortunately, it was set on each individual page, instead of in a css.

Comment: +1 Well, that's part of the game maintaining other people's code.